# Phonegap cordova, how to play local mp4 file on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova, html5-video

I would like to play `local MP4 file` in **Cordova Phonegap app (version 3.4.1)**.

I would like to have a image, and on tap on image, a local video should start in full screen.

How can I do this using the Cordova and Phonegap?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Ali,
Can you confirm that you are facing this problem on iOS or Android? Or both?

Comment: I'm looking for iOS platform right now.